# Make tr replace only exact characters given in arguments

Tags: unix, tr

I'm trying to convert filenames to remove unacceptable characters, but `tr` doesn't always treat its input arguments exactly as they're given.

For example:

```console
$ echo "(hello) - {world}" | tr '()-{}' '_'
_______ _ _______
```

...whereas I only intended to replace `(`, `)`, `-`, `{` and `}`, all the characters between `)` and `{` in ASCII collation order were replaced as well -- so every letter in the input also became a `_`!

Is there a way to make tr replace only the exact characters given in its argument?

Comment: Note for the future that there's no good reason to use tr for this -- bash's built-in string manipulation is more than capable enough. `${str//[abcd]/_}` f/e will change all of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` to underscores.

Comment: "an answer to this OTHER than scripting the changes to the filenames" write your scipts in a way that can handle arbitrary filenames?  `find -print0` and `xargs -0` is what I usually use

Comment: @CharlesDuffy GREAT, I can either change the Q or whatever, but that hint isn't quite enough and I'd be delighted to get it as an "answer." Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @DanielFarrell Too late Daniel, there's only, oh, close to 30 years of script writing at this organization... And these filenames are RARE in this environment, it's just a recent cache of files needs to be ingested and managed.

Comment: To understand the immediate problem, read the EXTENDED DESCRIPTION in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html. But yes, if you're willing to accept answers that don't describe tr behavior but just provide an alternate way to achieve your stated goal, that opens up a lot of solutions, and I'd be glad to provide one as an answer.

Comment: btw, I do _strongly_ agree with Daniel that building robust scripts that don't use `eval`-equivalent syntax, consistently quote correctly, and otherwise work right no matter what filenames are in use is the Right Thing, but for purposes of this question that's neither here nor there. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll make a new question for that - how's that! I STILL have no clue why tr translated that e into an _! ... It'll take me a few moments...

Comment: btw, your testStr having `$i` in double quotes means the content it has after being expanded depends on variables that are locally set. It'd be much more robust (in terms of avoiding your script behaving different ways in different environments) to specify `testStr` (and other variables) in single quotes instead of double quotes. (There are some changes -- like removing extra backslashes -- that'll be needed to convert).

Comment: (it'd also be good to make sure `testStr` actually _contains_ all the underscore characters)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK, it's up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73682880/how-to-create-new-names-for-files-with-problematic-characters-for-use-in-an-exis

Comment: Spending some time with the spec, I believe your original code was in undefined space -- meaning, it's allowed to convert `e` because it's allowed to convert _anything it wants_. The standard for `tr` defines behavior when a backslash is followed by three digits (indicating an octal sequence), or when it's followed by a character in the table at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tagtcjh_2.

Comment: Not adding this as an answer, because it doesn't actually explain the observed behavior -- while getting into a space where only using well-defined behavior is pretty straightforward, explaining the actual behavior is less so -- and I do have projects I ought to be working on. The "let's just get into well-defined space" approach with tr would probably call for expressing each character as a `\###` octal-representation string; `\133` for `[`, for example, `\135` for `]`, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy GAWD that's _ugly!_ ... I did NOT realize that and if you hadn't called it out, I'd have been baffled "forever." Perhaps I'll write up an answer based on your comments tomorrow as I, too, have, as we New Orleanians say, "More Fish To Fry!"

Comment: Heh. There's _also_ a typo I missed in early readthroughs, and am a little embarrassed about. `tr "toUnderscores" "$underscore"` is not `tr "$toUnderscores" "$underscore"` And `e` is definitely part of the string `toUnderscores`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'M MORE EMBARRASSED THAN YOU ARE! Oops!

Comment: After doing the work to build a solution that converts strings that tr can't handle into a form that it can, it's almost a bit sad to no longer need it. Whadayasay we cover this up and edit your question into one that actually needs the answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr`'s syntax is surprisingly complicated. It supports ranges, character classes, collation-based equivalence matching, etc.

To avoid surprises (when a string matches any of that syntax unexpectedly), we can convert our literal characters to a string of `\###` octal specifiers of those characters' ordinals:

```bash
trExpressionFor() {
  printf %s "$1" | od -v -A n -b | tr ' ' '\\'
}

trL() { # name short for "tr-literal"
  tr "$(trExpressionFor "$1")" "$(trExpressionFor "$2")"
}
```

...used as:

```console
$ trExpressionFor '()-{}'
\050\051\055\173\175
$ echo "(hello) - {world}" | trL '()-{}' '_'
_hello_ _ _world_
```

Comment: I obviously have a LOT to learn about tr - and bash! But then, I usually code on other languages! ... That's my excuse and I'm sticking to it! ;-) And NO, I won't screw with your edits, you did a fine job and I for one appreciate it!