# How to create new names for files with problematic characters for use in an existing bash scripted environment?

Tags: bash, filenames

The goal is to get rid of (by changing) filenames that give headaches for scripting by translating them to something else. The reason is that in this nearly 30 year Unix / Linux environment, with a lot of existing scripts that may not be "written correctly", a new, large and important cache of files arrived that have to be managed, and so, a colleague has asked me to write a script to help with "problematic filenames" and translate them. They've got a list of chars to turn into dots, such as the comma, and another list to turn into underscores, such as whitespace, as but two examples and ran into problems which [I asked about over here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73682784/bash-tr-of-characters-to-dots-works-as-expected-but-not-to-underscores)

I was using tr to do it, but commenters to it said I should perhaps ask just about this instead of how to get tr to work. So, I have!

Comment: Just being curious: What is so problematic with a comma in a filename?

Comment: @user1934428 IDK, I didn't ask them. I just took their lists for toDots and toUnderscores and went with it. -shrug-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) can do this for you.

Note that unlike when using `tr` (as requested on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73682784/bash-tr-of-characters-to-dots-works-as-expected-but-not-to-underscores)), when using parameter expansion you don't need to use backslashes inside your character class definitions: put the expansion in double quotes and bash will treat the results of that expansion as literal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 
toDots='\,;:|+@#$%^&*~'
toUnderscores='}{]['"'"'="()`!'

# requires bash 5+: if debug=1, then print what we would do instead of doing it
runOrDebug() {
  if (( debug )); then
    printf '%s\n' "${*@Q}"
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}
 
renameFiles() {
  local name subDots subBoth
 
  for name; do
    subDots=${name//["$toDots"]/.}
    subBoth=${subDots//["$toUnderscores"]/_}
 
    if [[ $subBoth != "$name" ]]; then
      runOrDebug mv -- "$name" "$subBoth"
    fi
  done
}
 
debug=1 renameFiles '[/a],/;[p:r|o\b+lem@a#t$i%c]/@(%$^!/(e^n&t*ry)~='
```

Note that `toUnderscores` is (except for the single quote in the middle) in *single* quotes, so all the backslashes in it are part of the variable's data rather than being syntax; because globs use character class syntax from REs, they're parsed as POSIX regular expression character class syntax.

See a demonstration of the technique running at https://ideone.com/kKE7IJ

Comment: I thought your comment about escaping [ and ] for tr was REALLY IMPORTANT because, while I guess I SHOULD have realized that, I had completely overlooked it. So, go ahead and post an answer over there, if you would! ;-) And THANKS, this is just the help I needed! And, you've helped me in the past, so thanks AGAIN!

Comment: On my way out the door to go for a walk (been inside too long), but if there aren't any good answers there when I get back I'll spend some time looking at the tr specification I linked so I can write up a good explanation of exactly what it's doing in the absence of the slashes, amend that into the answer there, and undelete it. (Don't want to have two answers that are too close to each other; if it's going to be two separate questions, then they should have answers that are distinct enough to justify the split).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Don't forget that you can double quote the variables inside a parameter expansion, so you don't even need to glob-escape the characters in `toDots` and `toUnderscores`.

Comment: @Fravadona, an excellent point, thank you -- I didn't remember until you pointed it out that that worked inside a character class definition, as opposed to in the outer context.

Comment: @Fravadona Would you care to expound on that an another answer? I'd be glad to upvote it! ;-)

Comment: @RichardT, for what it's worth, I edited this to take advantage of the syntax Fravadona pointed out is available -- see how now there are no longer extra backslashes in the definitions of `toDots` and `toUnderscores`, and instead there are double quotes in `["$toDots"]` and `["$toUnderscores"]`

Comment: If two files map to the same name, you will overwrite the one you have already renamed earlier. Since the OP did not specify what he wants to achieve in this case, you could at least use `mv -S` to catch this case.

Comment: @user1934428, ...hmm. I'm a bit dismayed to discover that POSIX has no equivalent to `mv -S`; the only way to not proceed with overwrite without introducing dependencies other than bash itself on the host OS is to use `-i`. There is of course the ability to do a separate test beforehand, but with attendant risk of race conditions (`if [ -e "$subBoth" ]; then echo "Skipping rename of $name to $subBoth, as destination already exists" >&2; else mv -- "$name" "$subBoth"; fi` or such).